# MySQL charset=UTF-8 with ConnectionReset=True is not working

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, utf-8, character-encoding

I've a connection string like below

> "Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd='abcd';Database=testdb;charset=utf8;ConnectionReset=True;"

Any insertion to a database table column with unicode character is inserted as special characters. Everything works fine if i remove "ConnectionReset=True;" from my connection string.
Any idea whats going on here?

**Note:** I believe my code is fine because insertion of unicode is fine when I remove `ConnectionReset=True;` part from the connection string.

Comment: Any idea whats going on here? No!... Where is the connection string defined is it a programming language?

Comment: Of course it is. C# .net core with Entity framework

Comment: You should include some C# code where you use this connection string.. i've already updated the question with the extra tags.

Comment: PLease see the updated question

Comment: My issue is some conflict between charset and connectionreset properties

Comment: "It seems that the .NET connector is resetting CharSet option to its default settings when reacquiring a connection from a pool with ConnectionReset=true.

I'm working with utf-8 and I have CharSet=utf8 in my connection string. When I reuse a connection by reopnening it with Pooling=true and ConnectionReset=true, I get bad utf-8 characters in my database tables." https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85185

Comment: Is there any solution for this??

Comment: Should 'reset' come before 'charset'??

Comment: @RickJames I checked that too. no hope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are encountering [MySQL Bug #85185](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85185): "ConnectionReset pooling option does not preserve CharSet option value".

It's a good idea to use `ConnectionReset=true`; however, this has the side-effect of resetting the connection character set to the server default, which isn't what you want. I can think of two workarounds:

1. Use [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector), a replacement ADO.NET MySQL connector library that fixes this (and many other) Connector/NET bugs
2. Execute `connection.ExecuteNonQuery("SET NAMES utf8mb4");` after each call to `connection.Open()`. This will fix the connection character set after a connection is reset when it's returned from the pool.

Finally, the MySQL `utf8` character set is *not* actually UTF-8, so [use `utf8mb4` instead](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434).